# Why is the Dollar Sign not working?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, synergy

I have been tinkering around with Synergy today (Windows Desktop Server, OSX Laptop Client) and I must say I am VERY pleased.

However, I have one issue I need to resolve in order to use Synergy at all.

**My dollar-sign (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>) is not working.**

The key <kbd>4</kbd> produces the number "4". <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> produces nothing. Not blank--just no reaction whatsoever.

I have verified that <kbd>Shift</kbd> works. <kbd>Shift</kbd> works with <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd> and so on. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> works on the host (Windows).

I have also verified that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> from the actual laptop keyboard works properly.

Obviously, it is not a "Swapped modifiers" issue, since it works with all the other keys.  I really need this to take care of the work I do with PHP, so I would be really glad if someone could assist me in troubleshooting the issue.

[Here is the Level 1 debug log from `synergys`](http://pastebin.com/dQ4iscU4)

What you see in this debug is me doing several things:

1. Press `Shift`
2. Press `3`
3. Release `3`
4. Press `4`
5. Release `4`
6. Release `Shift`

Comment: What does the debug log for `synergys` say?

Comment: What's happening is when you press shift-3, it sends ASCII code 35 (`#`). But when you press shift-4, it appears to send ASCII code *164*, rather than 36 (`$`)

Comment: Can you post your `synergy.conf` file from the server?

Comment: I noticed that as well, the numbers seemed a bit off. Not being particularly successful in locating the .conf file, since the host is a Windows machine. Will poke back once I find it!

Comment: I found no conf-file, but I had an option to save my configuration, so I did that and checked the file, but it only contained basic information on which screens go left, right, their names, etc. Nothing keysym/ascii-specific.

Comment: Hm. What version of synergys are you using? I have had to use an older version on my macs, v1.3.6 to be specific...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's a solution or a defeat, but I tried out [ShareMouse](http://www.share-mouse.com/), and it took care of my problems without any hassle. Perfect switching between host/client layouts and easier setup. Yay. :) Thanks for all the help, people!

Answer (score 0):

When you press Shift-4, the character code [164](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a4/index.htm) is being sent. This is the Unicode currency symbol ¤, which is often reinterpreted to be a pound £ or euro symbol € by the operating system. This suggests that the computer you're typing on is using a non-U.S. keyboard layout. Try switching the computer to use a U.S. keyboard layout.

Comment: Man, this is messed up. I tried restarting the host after changing the host keyboard layout, and now I am getting the dollar sign, but other characters are messed up. Slash has become 7, etc. Seems like I will not be able to use this program reliably, then! Too bad, I was enjoying it a lot..

Comment: Definitely sounds like you have keyboard layout issues.

Comment: Sounds like synergy isn't working to me...

Comment: @MichaelHampton, you know of *any* keyboard layout in which the slash key produces `7` and there is no `Shift+4` at all? `o.O`